# Printing a dynamic 2D array, C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I'm attempting to print the contents of a dynamically allocated 2D array. However, when I try to subscript an element I get an error. Any help would be appreciated.

The snippet that makes the array:

```
   char ** m_points = new char * [m_height];

   for (int y_i=0; y_i<m_height; y_i++)
   {
       m_points[y_i] = new char[m_width];

       for (int x_i=0; x_i<m_width; x_i++)
           m_points[y_i][x_i] = ' ';   
   }
```

This is supposed to print the arrays contents (`cout << m_points[y_i][x_i]` is where the error is occurring):

```
   for (int y_i=0; y_i<m_height; y_i++)
   {       
       for (int x_i=0; x_i<m_width; x_i++)
           cout << m_points[y_i][x_i];

       cout << endl;
   }
```

Error:

```
invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
```

Comment: Which compiler? Works fine on GCC 4.6.2.

Comment: Your code seems to compile for me on GCC 4.4, with all (and extra) warnings enabled; so I fail to reproduce the error.  If there is something different you would like me to try, please advise.

Comment: I'm using G++, `g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -o executable_name some_object_files`.

Comment: G++ version 4.6.1 on a Xubuntu 11.10 i386 VM.

Comment: Well, irreproduceable errors are some of the most irritating ones, aren't they?  One does not doubt that you have a real error but, even using your command-line options, I cannot reproduce it.  Sorry.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for trying anyway. If I find an answer, I'll post it.

Comment: What happens if you try casting the "char" to an int?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of a define (which obviously couldn't be the case), but not quite that. Don't forget to make that an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel like an idiot now, LOL. `m_points` was a member variable, and I declared it twice (once in the constructor, and once in the header file). After amending this issue, everything works perfectly. Thanks for the help, anyways.